# what's the difference in a decorator between calling a return and not

Tags: python, return, decorator

Let's assume we have a function:

```
@log
def now():
    print '2015'
```

---

### What's the difference between the two different decorators:

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        print 'call %s():' % func.__name__
        func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        print 'call %s():' % func.__name__
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you example you will see no difference at all because the function `now()` *returns* `None` and it's side effect is to `print "2015"`. However, if you consider the case where `now()` returns a value, you will start to get unexpected results.

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        print 'call %s():' % func.__name__
        func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper

@log
def now():
    return 1
```

Produces:

```
>>> x = now()
call now():   #print 'call %s():' % func.__name__
>>> print x
None
```

Now the value we were trying to get from the `now()` function is lost, because it was never returned as the value of `wrapper`, and in turn is never returned as the value of `log`.

Comment: thx,I did not expect such a situation that the func with a return

Answer (score 0):

If the wrapper does not include a `return` statement, the return value of the function will not be returned.

In other words, the function, once wrapped, will stop returning a value.

This might be desired behaviour, but a wrapper generally shouldn't change the function signature (although Python's functions do not really have a signature).